# How to run a test and restore previous component state

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am running some test on my react component.

Inside my `describe` i have multiple `it`.

like so :

```
describe('Check Component', () => {


  let wrapper;
  it('Init component', () => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Component/>
    )
  });

  it('+ Check filter : select years options', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('select[name="year"] > option')).toHaveLength(3)
  });


  it('+ Check change tab : personal stats', () => {
    wrapper.find('.tabs > .tab.personal').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('.tabs > .tab.personal').hasClass('selected')).toBeTruthy()
  });

 //many more it




});
```

On my component i have some button to filter a list, those action triggered by `simulate()` are changing my component initial dom tree which force me to `simulate()` the opposite action to restore to his initial state to perform more test which result in a lot of "rollback" if i have many filters

How can i restore , or isolate a test ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeEach() to get a new verison of wrapper before every test

```
describe('Check Component', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(()=>{
    wrapper = mount <Component />
  })
  it(...)
```

Comment: OK but on my test flow for some test i don't need my wrapper te refreshed or new
+ wont it result in high cost testing time and resource ?

Comment: You can use shallow instead of the mount to avoid the high-cost testing @LoicH